# Deleting all files in a selection of folders using applescript

Tags: applescript

I currently have a script that deletes all files in a particular file path, that are 14 days old:

```
tell application "Finder"

    delete (every file of folder "client" of folder "test" of folder "Dev, Con & Product" of folder "Google Drive" of folder (path to home folder) whose creation date is less than ((get current date) - 14 * days))

end tell
```

I am struggling to adapt this script so that instead of looking in the "`client`" folder and deleting all files, it looks in the "client 1", "client 2", "client 3" folders etc. and deletes all files that are 14 days old.

Any help on this would be great, 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that client 1 , client 2,...folders are still in same path (in folder "Dev, Con & Product", then keep current script, just changing "client" to "client 1"
if you have some many client folder, then you must use a repeat loop instead :

```
set myParent to (((path to home folder) as string) & "Google Drive:Dev, Con & Product:test") as alias
tell application "Finder"
set Myfolders to every folder of folder myParent whose name contains "Client"
repeat with OneFolder in Myfolders
    delete (every file of OneFolder whose creation date is less than ((get current date) - 14 * days))
end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot for your help!